# Decoration of the Text Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to achieve the following effect. How could I draw lines like this. Will `DecorationBox` allow me to obtain such a decoration?

**Text Widget**
[image: Text Widget]

Comment: *"Will DecorationBox allow me to obtain such a decoration?"* no, you need a custom `Decoration` class (a class that extends `Decoration`)

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with Flutter with the any of the built-in widgets.
However, you can easily make a widget that does the job for you like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DecoratedText extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double height, width, topOffset, childWidthFraction;
  final BoxBorder border;
  final BorderRadiusGeometry borderRadius;
  final Color textBackgroundColor;
  const DecoratedText({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    this.height = 20.0,
    this.width = 200.0,
    this.topOffset = -8.0,
    this.childWidthFraction = 0.75,
    this.border,
    this.borderRadius = const BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(
        5.0,
      ),
    ),
    this.textBackgroundColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: height,
          width: width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: border == null
                ? Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade700)
                : border,
            borderRadius: borderRadius,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: topOffset,
          child: Container(
            child: child,
            color: textBackgroundColor == null
                ? Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor
                : textBackgroundColor,
            width: width * childWidthFraction,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
DecoratedText(
  child: const Text(
    'Configuration',
  ),
),
```

[image: Here is what it looks like]

What does each variable mean:
`child` use this for your `Text` widget.

`width` & `height`: the width and the height of the border.

`topOffset` is the top offset of the child widget.

`childWidthFraction` the should be a `double` ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 and represent the fraction of the width passed in via the `width` property that the child widget is allowed to take up.

`border` & `borderRadius` allows you to customize the look of the border.

`textBackgroundColor`: this should match the background color of the parent widget of your `DecoratedText` widget, so you can achieve the wanted effect.

**NOTE**:
If you increase the font size of the `Text` widget you will probably have to play around witht the `width`, `height` and `topOffset` values of the `DecoratedText` widget.

Comment: this is a typical "decoration", so it should be implemented with a custom `Decoration` class (a class that extends `Decoration` class) - check some example [here](https://gist.github.com/pskink/da43c327b75eec05d903fa1b4d0c4d3e#file-decorations-dart-L7) - it uses: `decoration: CornerDecoration`

Comment: I see what you are talking about, but since the user who asked the question is probably new to Flutter and won't understand such complicated code. So I think that making it a widget will do the job good enough.

Comment: the code i linked is "complicated" since it supports animations (morphing from one decoration to another), for a case like in original question it is as simple as [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xp22F8zt66/)

Comment: and if you want to see how that morphing works in action add [CornerDecorationTest](https://gist.github.com/pskink/da43c327b75eec05d903fa1b4d0c4d3e#file-decorations-dart-L7) to your app and click the center `OutlineButton`